# Benefits of confirmed 0-value transactions?

Tags: transaction, data

As a transaction receiver, is there an advantage to wait until a 0-value transaction is confirmed or not?

The only case I can think of is, when the tangle should act as a "spam filter". When the receiver only accepts confirmed transactions to reduce spam in his application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When receiving a transaction the node checks the presence of *value* inconsistencies in the subtangle of the chosen tips.

Now, since a 0-value transaction has no value by definition, once it has been inserted in the Tangle I think it should be considered valid, it doesn't contain anything that can render it invalid or inconsistent with the Tangle.

With this in mind, if for some reason I have to read a 0-value tx in order for my application to work, I can trust this tx even if it isn't confirmed yet.

This isn't a really secure way to use 0-value txs. If you want to use them in your application you should insert some validation-checks into the payload/message fragment, and your application should check it independently from the Tangle confirmation.

What I mean is that I can write on a 0-value tx: "USA President is Jim Carrey" and the system will accept this tx. It is the application duty to check what's inside a tx message, confirmed or not.

I hope I made myself clear :)

Answer (score 0):

"This isn't a really secure way to use 0-value txs. If you want to use them in your application you should insert some validation-checks into the payload/message fragment, and your application should check it independently from the Tangle confirmation"

can you add signature to make "USA President is Jim Carrey" confimed by the sender?

Comment: You cannot modify the validation mechanism in IOTA or "add a signature". You can create a protocol exploiting IOTA system. For example in your protocol you accept only txs with a message written in a specific way: 2000 trytes containing the real message, 100 trytes containing the parameters of your message, 87 trytes containing a signature that you decide to use. Your application will read the message field of specific 0-value txs and check if these message are "encoded" as your protocol states. Only "good" messages will be accepted by your application, but "bad" will be accepted by Tangle.

Comment: I didn't mean adding signature to modify the validation mechanism in IOTA,i meant adding digital signature that no one besides the sender of tx can modify the data being sent while the tx is in process..to prove that the message originates from a specific person(ie the sender)

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. I mean, anyone would be able to pick a 0-value tx and crate another one with the same address but a different message! The only solution I see is to have some sort of signature inside the message, but that would be external to IOTA validation (for example MAM uses something like this, if you're interested there are video-tutorial on youtube by MobileFish)